# browsing image sequence with a slider in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to show a sequence of images using Bokeh and hope to interactively slide through or play the sequence. When I run my script it shows the first image but the image is not updating when I drag the slider or click the play button. My code is as following:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import  ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, SingleIntervalTicker, Slider, Button, Label
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral1
from skimage.external import tifffile as T


img=T.imread('C:/Users/UserXX/Desktop/Image_Sequence.tif')
sources={}
frames=list(range(0,img.shape[0]))

for frame in frames:
    sources[frame]=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(image=[img[frame,:,:]]))

source1 = sources[0]


p_img = figure(plot_width=694, plot_height=520, x_range=[0,1388], y_range=[0, 1040])
label = Label(x=1.1, y=18, text=str(frames[0]), text_font_size='70pt', text_color='#eeeeee')
p_img.add_layout(label)
p_img.image(image='image', x=[0], y=[0], dw=[1388], dh=[1040],source=source1, palette="Spectral11")

slider = Slider(start=frames[0], end=frames[-1], value=frames[0],step=1, title="Frame")

def animate_update():
    frame = slider.value + 1
    if frame > frames[-1]:
        frame = frames[0]
    slider.value = frame



def slider_update(attr, old, new):
    global source
    global sources
    frame = slider.value
    label.text = str(frame)
    source= sources[frame]



slider.on_change('value', slider_update)


def animate():
    if button.label == '► Play':
        button.label = '❚❚ Pause'
        curdoc().add_periodic_callback(animate_update, 200)
    else:
        button.label = '► Play'
        curdoc().remove_periodic_callback(animate_update)

button = Button(label='► Play', width=60)
button.on_click(animate)

l = layout([[p_img],[slider, button],], sizing_mode='scale_width')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Image_Sequence"
```

I am using this as an example:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/gapminder/main.py
I am not sure if the way that I am pass new image data to the source is correct or not.
Any suggestion?

Comment: try replace source = sources[frame] with source1.data = sources[frame].data. Since the source for the plot is source1, you need to change the associated data of source1. Otherwise moving the slider is simply defining source and not source1, which is being plotted. If that doesnt work ill try replicate your example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few different things that need fixing or improving in your code, so it's probably just easier to study and emulate this simplified complete  working example:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 100

x_ = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y_ = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
z_ = np.linspace(0, 10, N)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='xy')

data = np.sin(x+z)*np.cos(y)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(image=[data[:, :, 0]]))

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10))
p.image(image='image', x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10, source=source, palette="Spectral11")

slider = Slider(start=0, end=(N-1), value=0, step=1, title="Frame")

def update(attr, old, new):
    source.data = dict(image=[data[:, :, slider.value]])

slider.on_change('value', update)

curdoc().add_root(column(p, slider))
```

Please note that updates happen on every slider change, and even for 200x200 things can start to get slightly laggy (at least on my system). So you may also want to consider the technique described in [Throttling in Bokeh application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375961/throttling-in-bokeh-application/38379136#38379136)

[image]

Comment: I emulated your example and did get my images updated while I drag the slider.  However the images are updated very slowly, >3s per frame. The size of each frame is 1040X1388. But when I use images of size much smaller (100X100), it is updated pretty fast.  I am guessing it is the same issue that mention in this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908166/efficient-updates-of-image-plots-in-bokeh-for-interactive-visualization?rq=1

Comment: I still want to visualize the changing process from frame by frame but just with a faster speed. So I don't want to use Throttling in Bokeh. Will look at if there is other way to fix that.

Comment: If throttling is not an option then Bokeh may not be the right tool for your use case currently. The PR for base64 binary encoding has already been merged, improving things greatly from the SO question you linked, and the above image already reflects its inclusion. There is a possibility of further improvement using zero-copy direct transfer of array buffers in server app, but this would be future work. Even still I am not sure it will be enough to support fast interactions on images that size.

Comment: As a rough example: 1040 * 1388 * 8bytes (float64) * 30 fps means pushing  almost 350MB/s to the browser, at a *minimum*. I think we'd have to start talking about adding in compression schemes on top of the binary protocol, but that would be even further future work. Basically, it sounds like you want, and would be better off with a video solution of some sort, where compression is the norm.

Comment: Although your particular use case may be too large for Bokeh, I do think this answers the general question of "browsing image sequence with a slider in bokeh" and would be of use to other users. I would appreciate if you could mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your example. That is very helpful. And you are right, a video solution would be better  for my case currently.

Comment: Thanks! In case you'd like to follow it, an issue for future support of no-copy binary transfers is here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5984

Answer (score 2):

Base on @bigreddot's example. I got my code work to update images when dragging the slider or click button. Though for images with larger size, they are updating very slowly.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure,ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import  Slider, Button, Label
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
from skimage.external import tifffile as T


img_o=T.imread('C:/Users/UserXX/Desktop/Image_Sequence.tif')

frames=list(range(0,img_o.shape[0]))
img=np.flip(img_o,1)



source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(image=[img[0,:,:]]))


p_img = figure(x_range=(0,1388), y_range=(0, 1040))
label = Label(x=1.1, y=18, text=str(frames[0]), text_font_size='70pt', text_color='#eeeeee')
p_img.add_layout(label)
im=p_img.image(image='image', x=0, y=0, dw=1388, dh=1040, source=source, palette="Spectral11")

slider = Slider(start=frames[0], end=frames[-1], value=frames[0],step=1, title="Frame")

def animate_update():
    frame = slider.value + 1
    if frame > frames[-1]:
        frame = frames[0]
    slider.value = frame

ds=im.data_source    

def slider_update(attr, old, new):

    new_data=dict()
    frame = slider.value
    label.text = str(frame)
    new_data['image']=[img[frame,:,:]]
    ds.data= new_data



slider.on_change('value', slider_update)


def animate():
    if button.label == '► Play':
        button.label = '❚❚ Pause'
        curdoc().add_periodic_callback(animate_update, 200)
    else:
        button.label = '► Play'
        curdoc().remove_periodic_callback(animate_update)

button = Button(label='► Play', width=60)
button.on_click(animate)

l = layout([[p_img],[slider,button],], sizing_mode='scale_width')
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Image_sequence"
```

I mainly change the way how the data is passed to the source.
Another thing is this line would not work (the first frame is plotted but not updated)

```
im=p_img.image(image='image', x=[0], y=[0], dw=[1388], dh=[1040], source=source, palette="Spectral11")
```

After I change to:

```
im=p_img.image(image='image', x=0, y=0, dw=1388, dh=1040, source=source, palette="Spectral11")
```

The images can be updated. 
The only difference is the [ ] is get rid off from the parameter x, y, dw, dh. But I don't know why it will cause a problem.

Comment: glyph methods parameters can either *all* be data source column names, or *all* be sequence literals (in which case a CDS is made for you behind the scenes). They cannot be a *mix* of those things, which is what happens in the first line above.